# a multi line graph in highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

How to create a line chart in highcharts for the following json data.

```
[{x: "2018-02-12 17:10:48.000",y: "0.5", z: "1.4"},{x: "2018-02-14 15:10:48.000",y: "0.84", z: "3.45"},{x: "2018-0-15 17:10:48.000",y: "0.9", z: "2.5"}]
```

I have searched the documentation and demos but couldn't find anything that would work with the above JSON formatted data.
Y and Z values are the values to be plotted on the Y axis, and x values ,ie, the date, on the X axis.

Something like this: [image]

Comment: which chart from highcharts you want to create

Comment: @Deep3015 line chart

Comment: what does Z values do in line chart

Comment: Y and Z values are plotted on the Y axis(y1 and y2) as shown in the image in the question.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fdt9t2yr/1/  .Wrong '2018-0-15 17:10:48.000'' date, modified '2018-0-15 17:10:48.000' to '2018-02-15 17:10:48.000'

Comment: It Works! Can you put it in an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to use [Date.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to covert it into the required format.

```
var jsonD = [{
  x: "2018-02-12 17:10:48.000",
  y: "0.5",
  z: "1.4"
}, {
  x: "2018-02-14 15:10:48.000",
  y: "0.84",
  z: "3.45"
}, {
  x: "2018-02-15 17:10:48.000",
  y: "0.9",
  z: "2.5"
}];
var seriesData1 = [];
var seriesData2 = [];
jsonD.map((el) => {
  seriesData1.push({
    x: Date.parse(el.x), //conert to millisecond
    y: (Number(el.y)) //conert to Number
  });
  seriesData2.push({
    x: Date.parse(el.x),
    y: Number(el.z)
  })
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fdt9t2yr/1/) demo